# How to write Builder Pattern for class that extends abstract class in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance, design-patterns, abstract, builder

I have the "Client" class that extends abstract class "User":

```
public abstract class User {
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;

   //getters and setters
}

public class Client extends User{
    private List<Account> accountList;

    //getters and setters
}
```

I have written the builder for the "Client" class, but I can't have access to the User's fields (id, firstName, lastName, email) for use it all in building. How to do it?

```
public class Client extends User {
    private List<Account> accountList;

    public static Builder builder() {
        return new Client().new Builder();
    }


    public class Builder {
        private Builder() {
        }

        public Builder setAccountList(List<Account> accountList) {
            Client.this.accountList = accountList;
            return this;
        }

        public Client build() {
            return Client.this;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Make them protected instead of private to grant access to the derived class.

Comment: Use the getters and setters you left out instead of trying to access the fields directly...

Comment: You can make a `User.Builder` class that your `Client.Builder` can inherit from

Answer (score 0):

This is the solving:

```
 public final class Client extends User {
        private List<Account> accountList;
    
        public List<Account> getAccountList() {
            return accountList;
        }
    
        public void setAccountList(List<Account> accountList) {
            this.accountList = accountList;
        }
    
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
            Client client = (Client) o;
            return Objects.equals(accountList, client.accountList);
        }
    
        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(accountList);
        }
    
        public static Builder builder() {
            return new Client().new Builder();
        }
    
        public class Builder {
            private Builder() {
            }
    
            public Builder accountList(List<Account> accountList) {
                Client.this.accountList = accountList;
                return this;
            }
    
            public Builder id(Long id) {
                Client.this.setId(id);
                return this;
            }
    
            public Builder firstName(String firstName) {
                Client.this.setFirstName(firstName);
                return this;
            }
    
            public Builder lastName(String lastName) {
                Client.this.setLastName(lastName);
                return this;
            }
    
            public Builder email(String email) {
                Client.this.setEmail(email);
                return this;
            }
    
            public Builder password(String password) {
                Client.this.setPassword(password);
                return this;
            }
    
            public Builder role(User.Role role) {
                Client.this.setRole(role);
                return this;
            }
    
            public Builder dateOfBirth(LocalDate dateOfBirth) {
                Client.this.setDateOfBirth(dateOfBirth);
                return this;
            }
    
            public Client build() {
                return Client.this;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).